# Linq & Boolean Function

Tags: c#, linq, boolean

Is there any way one can apply a function with signature

```
bool IsOdd(int number);
```

to an array of integers and return whether any given integer in that array is odd in a single instruction? I know I can use

```
return (array.Where(IsOdd).Count() > 0);
```

but that implies calling two methods and making a comparison... Isn't there really a shorter way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.

To start with you could use the form of `Count` which takes a predicate:

```
return array.Count(IsOdd) > 0;
```

... but you don't want to do that. That code is still expressing a numerical comparison which is unnecessary. You want to ask if *any* item in the array *is odd*. In other words:

```
return array.Any(IsOdd);
```

Not only is this more expressive - it's also potentially *much faster*. As soon as `Any` finds a match, it will return `true` - whereas `Count` would have to iterate over the *whole* array to find out exactly how many matches there are.

Basically, whenever you see a LINQ query using `Count() > 0` you should think about using `Any` instead. In some cases with expression-tree-based queries such as LINQ to SQL it may not make a performance difference (*if* the query optimizer has visibility of the comparison with 0) but in LINQ to Objects it certainly can.

Comment: @Jon: As long as that `Count() > 0` part itself is inside a LINQ query, LINQ to SQL can optimize it away, but if you're writing `if (col.Count() > 0)`, LINQ to SQL will be doing the count for you, since there is obviously no way LINQ to SQL and C# are working together to optimize this for you. So even with LINQ to SQL (or any O/RM) it can make a difference.

Comment: Not to mention that `array.Any(IsOdd)` is about as close to real english as it gets in programming languages.

Comment: In addition, some ORMS (including LINQ to SQL) translate Any to Exsists which has the same short-circuiting behavior as Any in LINQ to Objects does.